Solving a recursive equation with a sum-product
I'm dealing with a recursive equation at work and struggling to solve it. The expression is:
$$a_j = \sum_{i=1}^j b_i + \sum_{i=1}^j a_{i-1}c_{i-1},$$
where $a_0=c_0=0$.
I've tried solving this for the first few values of $j$ but I'm not seeing a pattern appear. Is it possible to neatly solve for $a_j$ as a function only of the $b_i$ and $c_i$ values?

you havent defined $b,c$

They're just intended to be arbitrary sequences

try solving when all $b's$ are zero.

Then the a's are always 0 but that's just one trivial case

you could maybe do something with a Z-Transform
